# Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID

Tags: java, android

I try to show in MainActivity from another class by getter a value.
1st I make object and insert to him value from editText.
App crash with android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x28 What is wrong here ?

Check code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText, editText2;
    Button button, button2;
    TextView tV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        tV = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int a = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
                Calculations calc = new Calculations(a){
                };

                tV.setText(calc.getResult());

            }
        });
}
```

2nd Class

```
public class Calculations {

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public int result;

    public Calculations(int a){
        result = a * 10;
    }

    public Calculations(int a, int b){
        result = a * b;
    }

}
```

Here is my layout, maybe this will help
Here is my layout, maybe this will help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ge.ger.training.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.222"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.222"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.351" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Transfer value 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.121"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Transfer value 1 and 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.668" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.109"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.838" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: show your xml file
and try
Calculations calc=new Calculations(a);

Comment: Could you provide your layout code?

Comment: tV.setText(String.valueOf(calc.getResult()));
try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line with below in `onClickListener`

```
Calculations calc=new Calculations(a);
    tV.setText(String.valueOf(calc.getResult()));
```

Comment: thanks ! i will accept your answer, but I need wait 4 min for this

Comment: sure. I'll wait :)